# Is maintaining multiple "sites" using the same "web app" worth the added architecture and code complexity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

This may not at first seem like a code-related question. But it truly is, in the end a very high-level architecture question, which has implications for database design, and code architecture. So please give a good moment of thought before judging this as off-topic.

I imagine my situation is not unique in the industry and I would like to learn from others' experience.

I have run a topic based video education website for 8 years. Recently I've been inspired to make one or two other websites that are essentially the same thing, but with a different topic. Everything I'll need for these new sites I already have, including searching, indexing, external content hosting, backend jobs, mailers, etc.

I'm faced with the decision of do I fork the current website for each additional website, and make the 5% alterations required, and set up all of the other services, etc? Or do I try to basically cram a number of "websites" into the same app, that would basically key off of the domain name and give a different face and content (and registration, shopping cart, menus, content, etc)?

An example of this issue is Stack Overflow itself. They have many sites "branded" slightly differently. Do they maintain separate apps for each, or do they all run off of one app?
In the first case upgrades and code development will get out of sync and become a nightmare, and in the second, this will add a significant degree of complexity to, well, mostly everything.

Both seem pretty bad. Which is least bad?

ps, it's a ruby on rails app, in case by some magic, some gem exists for this kind of thing that I don't know about.

Answer (score 3):

If the functionality is the same then the you only need one app.  However, if you realize that at some point that the functionality of the app are diverging, then you could add another app to handle the diverging code but keep the common app to handle all the common functionality and convert to service oriented architecture.
Forking and maintaining two sets of identical code is a nightmare that should be avoided.

Comment: It's not really a question of "server", but of "app" (codebase). I could technically run two apps on the same server....

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at [multi tenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) -- the ability for multiple "tenants" to use a single application.

Modern terminology would label this as "cloud" software, although our current HTTP architecture prevents users maintaining state, preventing it from achieving that mantle.

---

**CMS**

In the terms of your app, you'd benefit from reading up about [CMS systems](https://hackhands.com/9-best-ruby-rails-content-management-systems-cms/).

Specifically, the likes of `tumblr` etc work with the exact pattern you want -- single application with...

- admin area
- front-end
- customization (background image, styling etc)
- users

--

For Rails, you'd be able to create a single instance of an application, with the following structure:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope constraints: AccountCheck do
   resources :posts, path: "" #-> url.com/
end

#lib/account_check.rb
module AccountCheck

    def initializer(router)
        @router = router
    end

    def self.matches?(request)
        Account.exists?(request.subdomain) && request.subdomain
    end

end
```

--

```
#app/models/account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
   has_many :posts
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts
   has_many :posts
end

#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The above will give you the ability to create a subdomain-centered system, which will display the posts for the current `account`:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @account = Account.find_by name: request.subdomain
       @posts   = @account.posts
   end
end
```

---

**Gem**

Very simple example, hopefully shows you how you'd achieve the multi-tenancy aspect.

If you wanted to take this even further, you'd want to look at data-scoping around the `Account` model. This cannot be done at the db-level in any other system than `pgsql`; for which there's a gem called [`apartment`](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) to manage [PGSQL schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html).

This is the best I have so far. There's a good book about this pattern by [`@Ryan Bigg`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15245/ryan-bigg) - https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails

Comment: Thanks for the info and useful links, I'll check them out. To clarify, my question isn't about "how" to achieve this, but which direction has proven to be the least perilous in the industry. An example of this issue is Stack Overflow itself. They have many sites "branded" slightly differently. Do they maintain separate apps for each, or do they all run off of one app?

Comment: I don't know about StackOverflow but I know Salesforce use a model similar to what I outlined above, as did Tumblr

Answer (score 0):

If you have total control over the "creative direction" for all the sites, maintaining all of them under a single site would be easier.

If you plan to retain a main site, with less frequent updates to the other sites, keeping them separate will have the advantage of reduced coupling - you can safely perform customization for a single site/app without impacting others, and avoid (further) raising the overall code complexity needed to accommodate competing requirements for multiple apps under the same site.